# SELECT from DB using Stored Procedures?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have tried to make a stored procedure like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_userStatUser $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_UserStatUser
(
IN userId INT,
OUT Played INT,
OUT Win INT,
OUT Points INT
)
BEGIN
SELECT played, win, points
INTO Played, Win, Points
FROM nf_users
WHERE id = userId;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I then try to get data from it like this:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connect,"CALL get_userStatUser()") or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

$played = $row['Played'];
$win = $row['Win'];
$points = $row['Points'];
```

But something is not right. I'm new to Stored Procedures and can not see where I go wrong? I get "Query fail:" with nothing in the error?

Any help is apreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You **must** pass the database handle to [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/mysqli_error).  You should be seeing an error or warning about this.  Please make sure that you have error reporting cranked all the way up to -1.

Comment: Check the case of the calling statement vs the proc definition. They don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stored Procedure needs 4 parameters

```
IN userId INT,
OUT Played INT,
OUT Win INT,
OUT Points INT
```

Given the way your PHP calls the Stored Procedure, you need to redefine the following:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_userStatUser $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_UserStatUser
(
IN userId INT
)
BEGIN
SELECT played, win, points
FROM nf_users
WHERE id = userId;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

your PHP

```
$given_userid = 372987;
$sql = mysqli_query($connect,"CALL get_userStatUser($given_userid)") or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

$played = $row['played'];
$win = $row['win'];
$points = $row['points'];
```

Give it a Try !!!